# Determining association (or not) of binary variable with continuous independent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data

(Fair warning: I am not a statistician.)

Let's say I run a bunch of trials. My (possibly) dependent variable is binary; my independent variable is continuous. For the sake of example, say each trial is {pass/fail, temperature}.

Is there a relatively straightforward way to determine if pass rate is not associated with temperature?

As is far too often the case with statistical questions, this seems trivial at first (just use a logistic regression!), but very quickly becomes complex. (Imagine the case that temperature is uniformly distributed over a range, and failures occur within a window centered on the mean temperature...)

Comment: If you fit a flexible model, such as using splines to describe the low-high-low failure probability in your example, you can fit more than just a linear trend. However, you have just one predictor variables, right? How does it look when you plot it against the outcome? Perhaps even post that graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few level in which this can be approached:

1. If you are OK with assuming a linear functional form: If you expect the relation to be one-directional, e.g. the *fail* class to be associated mostly with one side of the temperature distribution you sampled, and successes ("pass") mostly with the other "end" of the temperature distribution, then the [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Area-under-curve_(AUC)_statistic_for_ROC_curves) is a fairly simple, non parametric test for such dependence.
2. Assuming a nonlinear (but mostly known) functional form: If the relationship is not expected to be linear, but you do have some notion of what form other than linear it is likely to take. For example, you might expect the successes (positive class) to be mostly concentrated in one region of the temperature scale, and the other class (fails) to occur mostly on the ends. In such case, you should check your assumptions directly by first fitting the appropriate model to your data. In the example above, you could perform a logistic regression with both $temp$ and $temp^2$ as your independent variables. You can then basically go back to case #1, except here you'd check your model's *predictions* against the actual pass/fail binary values using the Mann-Whitney, instead of the temperature directly.
3. Unknown functional form: If you would not like to commit to any specific functional form, but still want to test for potential association, I would consider re-framing your statistical test as follows: consider that any detectable difference between the **distribution** of the temperature samples that are associated with one class, from one side, and the distribution of those associated with the other class, on the other side, is an indirect indication of statistical dependence. Based on that, your statistical hypothesis test may sound like this: "Can I test for whether the PDF of the temperature samples associated with pass-values is significantly different than the PDF of the samples associated with the fail-values?"

This hypothesis can be tested with a few different tests, one popular such test is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test.

Footnote: The *U statistic* calculated in the Mann-Whitney test is very closely related to the ROC AUC statistic which is in common use to assess classifiers. The similarity to your problem stems from the fact that in classification tasks, we want to know the extent to which the predicted probabilities - essentially just a continuous function of one or more independent variables -  succeeds in separating the two classes.

Comment: I'd prefer not to assume the form of the relationship, as I actually have many of these series (>1k series of >1k points each), and empirically speaking they appear to have many different distributions. That being said, #3 - checking if passes and fails are drawn from the same distribution - makes a lot of sense; I'll dig into the KS test and friends. Thanks for the pointer!